# Como trabalhar com Enums do tipo CHAR, utilizando C# e Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, fluent-api

Gostaria de saber como mapear minha entidade que utiliza um Enum do tipo `char` pelo Entity Framework, utilizando FluentApi.

Tenho o seguinte Enum:

```
public enum Zona
{
    Norte = 'N',
    Sul = 'S'
}
```

E a minha Entidade:

```
public class Local
{
    public Guid RioId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Zona Zona { get; set; }
}
```

Configuro da seguinte maneira a entidade:

```
public class LocalMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Local>
{
    public LocalMapping()
    {
        ToTable("Local");

        HasKey(r => r.LocalId);

        Property(r => r.Nome).IsRequired();

        Property(r => r.Zona).IsRequired(); 
    }
}
```

Como faço para cadastrar meu Enum Zona como `varchar(1)` no banco de dados, de forma que quando salve um Local com Zona Norte, fique salvo no Banco o caractere N

Comment: C# ñ tem `enum char`. É melhor usar um código.

Comment: Segue o link da solução [Entity Framework Enum Support - Code First ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh859576(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia utilizar de um enum próprio:

```
public class EnumBase
{
    public EnumBase()
    {
        Locals = new HashSet<Local>();         
    }

    public int EnumBaseId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public int? ValorEnum { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Local> Locals { get; set; }
}

public class Local
{
    public Guid RioId { get; set; }
    public EnumBase Zona { get; set; }
    public int? ZonaId { get; set; }
    public Zona Zona { get; set; }
}
```

Então você Mapeia no EnumBase:

```
HasMany(c => c.Locals)
                  .WithOptional(x => x.Zona)
                  .HasForeignKey(c => c.ZonaId);
```